# Delete OPTIONS call fails when url contains %00(http://localhost:5432/rest/delete/author/my%00author)

Tags: preflight

When the url contains %00 the OPTIONS request failed with 400 Bad request. But if it is present in query parameters like ?name=my%00test then OPTIONS request returns 200 OK. Below is the Request and Response headers for that OPTIONS call.

```
Request Headers:
-----------------
OPTIONS /rest/api/books/test%00test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Referer: http://localhost:5432/
Origin: http://localhost:5432
Connection: keep-alive

Response Headers:
-----------------
HTTP/1.1 400 
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 795
Date: Sat, 20 Mar 2021 09:57:30 GMT
Connection: close
```

Comment: 400 is an error generated by the server. And the server probably treats query parameters and url paths differently ... So you'll have to take a look at the server why it rejects the request ... But nobody can say that from the request alone. %00 probably is an invalid character in the path ..

Comment: Hi @derpirscher, thanks for your answer. Am getting this error during the OPTIONS call, server didn't receive any request from UI, once the action is done in UI am getting this error. As you mentioned this might be an invalid character.

Comment: If you get a 400 error with response headers, this has to come from the server (or maybe some proxy inbetween ...)